# Further scaling plotted data by year into intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am practicing visualizing data with R with a dataset on certain incidents worldwide. I created a data frame only containing the number of incidents per year with the `plyr` count function.

```
library(plyr)
df_incidents <- count(df$iyear)
names(df_incidents)[names(df_incidents) == "x"] <- "year"
names(df_incidents)[names(df_incidents) == "freq"] <- "incidents"
df_incidents
```

Output:

```
year     incidents
1970     651
1971     471
1972     568
1973     473
1974     581
... all the way to 2018
```

I visualised the above data with `ggplot(df_incidents,aes(x=year,y=incidents)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")` which returned a histogram of incidents per year, but I am unable to further group `year` into intervals of 5 years.

Should I alter my `ggplot` statement to scale the data or further process my `df_incidents` data frame into distinctive groups of approx 5 years from 1970?

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to _not_ construct the counts dataframe, and just do `ggplot(df, aes(iyear)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an approach using bars with `scale_x_continuous()` or using a new variable defined by `cut()` function. Here the approaches:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
#Data
df_incidents <- data.frame(year=1978:2018,
                           incidents=round(runif(41,500,1000),0))
#Plot option 1
ggplot(df_incidents,aes(x=year,y=incidents))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black',fill='cyan')+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1978,2018,by=5))
```

Output:

[image]

And the second approach:

```
#Plot option 2
df_incidents %>%
  mutate(Cutyear=cut(year,breaks = seq(1978,2018,by=5),include.lowest = T,right = F)) %>%
  group_by(Cutyear) %>%
  summarise(incidents=sum(incidents,na.rm=T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Cutyear,y=incidents))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',color='black',fill='cyan')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can bin your years into categories like below:

```
 df_incidents %>% mutate(Binned= cut(year, breaks = c(1970, 1975, ....,2020))) %>% 
 group_by(Binned) %>% summarize(Incidents= count(incidents)) %>% 
 ggplot(.,aes(x=Binned,y=Incidents)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```